# Blackberry themes - Writing dynamic text to background

Tags: blackberry, themes

I'm designing a blackberry theme with 'Blackberry Theme Studio 6' and I need to write dynamic text to the background everyday. Being more specific, I'd like to write a list of calendar events so they appear in the main screen.

How can I do that?

I've been developing blackberry java applications for a while but this is the first time I give themes development a try. I've been trying to find a good tutorial or posts in here related to what I need but I couldn't find anything similar.

I posted this within the blackberry development forum but I nobody answered my question. I hope somebody does in here...

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I guess it's not the only one...

Generating SVG (Scaled Vector Graphics) I managed to create an image using only text (SVG use something similar to XML).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="252.89000pt" width="493.28000pt" version="1.0" y="0.00000000" x="0.00000000" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <text style="font-size:72px;font-style:oblique;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;font-stretch:normal;text-align:start;line-height:125.00000%;writing-mode:lr;text-anchor:start;fill:#fff;fill-opacity:0.49999997;stroke:#000;stroke-width:3.0000000;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4.0000000;stroke-dasharray:6.0000000 3.0000000;stroke-dashoffset:0.00000000;stroke-opacity:1.0000000;font-family:Bitstream Vera Sans" xml:space="preserve" transform="translate(6.201104,5.167586)" y="101.34265" x="398.91016">SVG</text>
</svg>
```

Later I used BlackBerry API's Graphics objects to convert from SVG to PNG.